# How to read contents of .ZFO file (Datová schránka)

Tags: javascript, xml

I have opened the ZFO file in a code editor and saw that it resambles a XML file. It does contain some informations and also some files in a some format. Hoever the XML cannot be parsed.

Is there any way to retrieve all info inside?

Answer (score 0):

The XML is signed with some kind of certificate. The files is filled with some special character.

To read the file using classical browser API I uave used following steps:

```
let text = await response.text();
// The file contains a lot of weird characters (`��`) that need to be removed (possibly part of signature)
text = text.replaceAll('��', '');
// The file also contains a header that needs to be removed before it can be parsed as a XML
text = text.substring(text.indexOf('<q:MessageDownloadResponse'));
// The file also contains signature footer that needs to be removed
text = text.substring(0, text.lastIndexOf('</q:MessageDownloadResponse>') + 27);
const document = new DOMParser().parseFromString(text, 'text/xml');
```

Then, everything can be extracted. The attachments are in `p:dmEncodedContent` element and are in `base64`. To extract them use following code:

```js
const fileAsBase64 = document.getElementsByTagName(node)?.[0]?.textContent;
cosnt file = new File([Uint8Array.from(atob(fileAsBase64), c => c.charCodeAt(0))]);
```